# Rails server runs tests instead of starting a server on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, server, rvm

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

rails -v:

```
Rails 5.1.6.1
```

rvm list:

```
=* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

rvm -v

```
rvm 1.29.7 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
```

rails -s:

```
Run options: --seed 22773
# Running:
Finished in 0.000567s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Looks like Rails making tests instead running the server. 
How can I solve it?

It happened on any application. No matter new or downloaded from Internet.

Answer (score 4):

The `server` command is not a "hyphenated" param.

I always execute using bundle, i.e., fire up your rails server using:

`bundle exec rails server`

or simply

`rails server`

or for even more brevity

`rails s`

For more info, use the `rails --help` command, or look [at the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server) :)

Comment: I did it in any way. rails s, rails server. It gave away tests output. 
Only **bundle exec rails server** gave me the working server. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks once again. Today I have tried to start rails server with simple rails s and it runned. I have no idea why it could not start in this way last week :)